# How to retrieve data that was push();

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I retrieve my user details such as the email, status, type? The red underlined is the data that I pushed `.push()`. Then the green underlined is the child for `_auth.currentUser!.uid`. Is it perhaps `.orderByKey()`?

```
 final refDataInstance =
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("users");
      refDataInstance.push().child('$auth').set({
        "email": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email,
        "uid": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid,
        "password": _passwordController.text,
        "type": "trainers",
        "status": "Unavailable",
```

[image]

Comment: Any read operations on `/users` will get that user's data. Can you edit your question to show the code that *reads* the data that is not doing what you expect it to do? --- Also: consider why you are calling `push()` to begin with. Unless there's a need to store multiple nodes per user, it's idiomatic to user `/users/$uid` to store their profile information.

Comment: Understood. I have removed push(). Used `/users/$uid` instead.